# Run one installation of Windows 10 in VirtualBox and on a real machine

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I use Linux as the main OS on my computer and Windows 10 in VirtualBox. I would like to switch to dual-boot, but in some special form. I would like to be able not to reboot every time I need Windows 10, and sometimes run it in VirtualBox (when I don’t need full performance) and have access to the same software and data.

So I would like to create a partition on the disk and transfer the system from VirtualBox there (and also copy the Windows boot files to the EFI partition where the Linux bootloader already exists and configure the Linux bootloader to display the OS selection menu). There are many instructions on how to transfer the system, so there should be no problems. Also, I'm going to configure VirtualBox on Linux so that it uses a real disk instead of a virtual one. For this, too, there are many instructions and problems should not be.

The main problem is how Windows 10 will behave if it sometimes loads in VirtualBox, and sometimes on a real device. Windows 10 is very good at finding new drivers, but the main question is that the old drivers are not deleted, otherwise each reboot will take a long time to re-search them. It is also necessary that the guest OS add-ons be deactivated on a real device and do not interfere with the correct operation of the OS.

Of course, I understand that while the virtual machine is running, you cannot mount its disk under Linux, otherwise the file system will be damaged.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible due to licensing issues.

Comment: @Ramhound, You are correct, licensing can be an issue but I do exactly this (but using VMWare Fusion on macOS not VBox on Linux) and it is certainly possible.  You need a license for both the VM and bare-metal boot as they are seen as different PCs.  I simply phoned MS and they gave me (for free) a Windows 10 retail key to use rather than the original digital license I had for the VM.  I've no idea if this is standard practice so I'm not posing it as an answer.

Comment: With regards to drivers, they are retained so boot does not take longer when swapping between native and VM boot.  VMWare automatically disables guest add-ons when it is seen as not running as a VM - OP would have to do the same with VBox I suppose.  What OP certainly should check (and clarify in the question) is whether the VBox VM is booting via EFI or BIOS as switching between legacy and EFI *will* confuse Windows.  Assuming both are EFI it will work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a hypervisor like VirtualBox be used to launch a virtualized OS which is also directly bootable?](https://superuser.com/questions/991976/can-a-hypervisor-like-virtualbox-be-used-to-launch-a-virtualized-os-which-is-als)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Windows 10 digital activation is tied to the hardware
platform.

Your emulated VirtualBox hardware is very different from that of the physical host,
so you risk Microsoft suspending your license for abuse of its licensing conditions.

Once you activated your license in VirtualBox, then VirtualBox is where it will stay.

A comment above by user @lx07 says that Microsoft Support may in such a case
give you another product key for free in such a case.
You may try, but there is no guarantee of success.